# Does violate DRY principle code with multiple return values?

Tags: javascript, dry

Does this code violate DRY principle?

```
if (notAuthorized) {
    return sendErrorCode(new ForbiddenException())
} else if (notValid) {
    return sendErrorCode(new InvalidArgumentException())
} else if (outDated) {
    return sendErrorCode(new Error())
} else {
    return sendResult(result)
}
```

I mean all these lines with sendErrorCode are error handling code.
Now I just send error code when an error occurs, but what if I need to log the error or send a request to analytics or something else I need to edit three lines of code.
Maybe I should wrap sendErrorCode in a more general function like handleError

Comment: Where do you repeat this `if`? Within each request handler?

Comment: "*what if I need to log the error or send a request to analytics or something else*" do it in `sendErrorCode`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NikKyriakides Now it only in one request handler

Comment: @Kaiido Then sendErrorCode will lost semantic

Comment: Why? IMM, a `sendErrorCode` method is semantically the correct place for *sending* an error to console or analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this violates the `Don't Repeat Yourself` principle by including a call to the error handler in several places. Although it's still a single place to modify, it'd be much nicer to modify only a single place, and leave concerns singleton per block. Thus `sendErrorCode` is always just that. It's not also a hidden error logger.

To adhere closer to DRY you should actually wrap your decision handling logic into either a new function or block and then decide if you want to send an error code later.

Here I've chosen a function that takes a possible Error library, and a possible result. If an Error is identified, return it. Otherwise return the result.

```
const isThereAProblem = ({ notAuthorized, notValid, outDated }, result) => {
  if (notAuthorized) return new ForbiddenException();
  if (notValid) return new InvalidArgumentException();
  if (outDated) return new Error();
  return result;
}
```

You could easily do this with branch logic instead, but you get the idea. Set once, handle once.

Later in your code

```
const result = isThereAProblem(possibleErrors, possibleResult);

if (result instanceof Error) return sendErrorCode(result);

return sendResult(result)
```

Now you have a single area to modify. Just make sure your exceptions are extensions of `Error` and you can check against it with the `instanceof` operator. To be `DRY` you must use the tools presented to you to by the language.

You should extract any code or functions that get called in multiple places into their own area so that it can easily be modified should requirements change. By moving the check for an error to a single place, thus removing any special handling to it's own area, and then only checking a generic case you have much more adaptable code. Now if you want to do something before sending back the error you can just expand the `if` block at the handler:

```
if (result instanceof Error) {
  console.error(result);
  return sendErrorCode(result);
}
```

One place to modify. Need more specialized logic for different types of errors instead? Put it in the `isThereAProblem` function

```
const isThereAProblem = ({ notAuthorized, notValid, outDated }, result) => {
  if (notAuthorized) {...}
  if (notValid) {...}
  if (outDated) {...}
  return result;
}
```

Either way now you can easily put handling for any possible error into a place where it makes more sense. Either where you identify the error, or where you handle the error.

Comment: Thank for reply. I see type checking in your code. Do you think we can't avoid it? https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#avoid-type-checking-part-1

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting that article. No matter what you do a type check if you do any if statement to check truthiness. The question is did you unroll it earlier, break DRY, and incur more developer debt, or did you do it later, use a type check, and incur less developer debt. I like less complex code. A single type check is a good exchange to manage extending the capabilities of my code later.